# how to get all the html input values in the same name to the servlet by ArrayList

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, arraylist

This is the HTML

```
<input type="hidden" value="Brand" name="labelValue" />
<input type="hidden" value="model" name="labelValue" />
```

This is the Servlet part

```
String values=request.getParameter("labelValue");
```

how to get this to a `ArrayList` and the input count is changing

Comment: use the `String[] request.getParameterValues(String)` method instead. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Returns an array of String objects containing all of the values the given request parameter has, or null if the parameter does not exist.
String[] values=req.getParameterValues("labelValue");

// Convert String array to arrayList. You can assign this to variable and use.
new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(values));
```